# Find root in a database tree-structured table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I have the following DB table describing a Bill Of Materials(BOM), basically a tree-structure:

```
Part(PartId, ParentId, PartName)
```

The Parts with **ParentId = 0** are finished product, meaning they do not compose any other product.

Now given a PartId I would like to know to which products it belongs by using plain SQL (MS SQL Server) or LINQ lambda

Comment: Post the product table structure..

Comment: which database?  Oracle has CONNECT BY

Comment: @JustinKirk there is no product table, Part with parentId = 0 are products

Comment: Difficult to do this with *plain* SQL. You will need to use either recursion or iteration - I would try iteration...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT PartId, ParentId
    FROM Part
    WHERE PartId = @PartId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.PartId, B.ParentId
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN #Part B
    ON A.ParentId = B.PartId
)
SELECT DISTINCT PartId 
FROM CTE
WHERE ParentId = 0
```